# Only Administrator can login to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-server-2003, sql-server-express

I'm using Windows Server 2003 to run a server application which utilizes SQL Express 2008. I'm also using Windows Terminal Services to host a bunch of thin clients, so I've had no need for active directory domain server and other stuff like that.

Now I have "small" problem regarding logging in to the SQL Server. Only the Administrator account can do this, even if I give my other (test) user administrator privileges by adding him to the Administrators group.

This is the error received: Cannot attach db file  to database  [Client 127.0.0.1]

I've already checked that the filepath is accessible by the user in question, and like I said, this works perfectly fine for the administrator user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I found the answer. Using SQL Management Studio i gave the "Users" group sysadmin permission for the database, now everything works as expected.

Comment: Are you sure you want these users to have sa rights? They could end up creating/dropping databases modifying rights. If that is your intention then ok but i hope you will continue to look into the issue and come up with a more appropriate resolution.

Answer (score 0):

What account is the SQL Server itself running under? Often it may be running under a domain service account, and it may not have permission to certain folders. Also, the C: drive has progressively become more locked down in Windows with regard to SQL Server database files.

Comment: Ok, just created a new user for the server to use as a login account, instead of using domain or network service... once again, even when this user has admin priveleges, no dice...

Comment: I believe it is named "sa"